# Detect URL with Javascript and apply CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a page I want to apply some CSS to, but it is dynamically generated by the CMS. The URL remains constant, so I thought I could stick this in the head of the template file to add the CSS to the page I want, but it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/products.html"))
{
document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">
.category-grid li:nth-child(4)
{
margin-left:115px;
}   
</style>");
}
});
</script>
```

There's probably some syntax off on my `document.write` statement, as that's where the error seems to occur, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems silly the back end does not do this.

Comment: Is there no way you can just write contextual css so that there is no script involved?

Comment: Are you getting some javascript error or it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are not properly terminated.

Also, you should **not** defer `document.write`, because it overwrites the current document. Also, compare the result from `indexOf` against `-1`. If the sub-string is not found, your previous code would still inject the script, because `!!-1` is true.

Your code can be fixed in this way:

```
<script>
if (location.href.indexOf("dev.obtura.com/products.html") !== -1) {
    document.write("<style>" +
    ".category-grid li:nth-child(4){" +
    "    margin-left:115px;" +
    "}" +
    "</style>");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `document.write()` in a jQuery "ready" handler. After the browser has finished building the DOM (which is what a "ready" handler implies), subsequent calls to `document.write` will destroy the page.

Instead of doing that, what you could do would be to use some CSS rules that you'd always include, but that are qualified by a body class:

```
.products .category-grid li:nth-child(4) {
   margin-left: 115px;
}
```

Then your script would add "products" to the `<body>` element's class when id decides it's the proper page.

Comment: Aha, didn't see this answer. Please for the sake of sanity do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are more satisfied with [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/). With this you can chose CSS or JS to load dynamically.

Such as this

```
yepnope({
  test : function(){return window.location.href.indexOf("dev.obtura.com/products.html") === -1},
  yep  : 'style.css',
  nope : 'products.css'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if your CSS styles are stored inside a stylesheet file you can use jQuery's append method instead of `document.write`

```
<script>
if (location.href.indexOf('dev.obtura.com/products.html') != -1) 
{
   //match!
   $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_stylesheet.css">');
}
</script>
```

HTH,

--hensson

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you can do it this way but I don't think it is a good way of doing it. This way of doing it seems like a pain to maintain and read. Some better ways I can think of:

- Add an additional class into the document that you can use to apply a css selector just for that document
- Add a style tag statically to just that page
- If you do want to use jQuery to apply it do something like this (not tested but should be close):

  $('.category-grid li:nth-child(4)').css('margin-left', '115px')
- yunzen's suggestion of using yepnope.